# What's the proper way to order by a scope of joined associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a `has_many :through` association.  The join model defines the proper order, which I need to sort on.  How can I sort on this order, keeping it DRY?

For example say a person has and belongs to many tasks, joined and ordered by an assignment:

```
class Person
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :tasks, through: assignments
end

class Assigment
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :task
  scope :ordered, ->{ order(position: :asc) }
end
```

How could I make use of that scope to order the person's tasks?

```
# Something like this would be nice, but unfortunately this generates a database
# query attempting to order on `people.position`, not `assignments.position`
person.tasks.merge(Assignment.ordered)

# So the less than ideal solution is to repeat myself
person.tasks.order(assignment: {position: asc})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can:

```
class Person
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :tasks,
           -> { merge(Assignment.ordered) },
           through: :assignments
end
```

Neat; I didn't know that. In my app, I have

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendance_requests
  has_many :users, 
            -> { merge AttendanceRequest.sort_by_user },
            :through    => :attendance_requests
end
```

When I call `Session.last.prospects`, AR produces

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM   "users"
       inner join "attendance_requests"
               ON "users"."id" = "attendance_requests"."user_id"
WHERE  "attendance_requests"."session_id" = $1
ORDER  BY "attendance_requests"."user_id" ASC
```

Comment: I've seen this, but this is effectively the same as my failed attempt above.  The problem is that the built query would attempt to sort on `people.position` instead of `assignments.position`, causing a database error.  I'll make a note of that in the question.

Comment: @numbers1311407 this works for me just fine. I've updated my answer with an example from my project.

Comment: Would this work for you then (given that the scope wasn't defined on the association as you have it now)?`Session.last.prospects.merge(AttendanceRequest.sort_by_user)`

Comment: Yes, I get the same result.

Comment: Weird, I'll have to circle back to this later and test further.  My app is pretty vanilla, but when I do the exact same thing the SQL is generated incorrectly as I noted.  I'm using postgres, I guess the adapter could be a factor?  What is your db?

Comment: @numbers1311407 which Rails release are you on? 4.0.1 changed the handling of order clauses. That might be related.

Comment: 4.0.1.  Which one were you on?  Also, pg 0.17.0